# Invalid syntax at equal sign

Tags: python-2.7, syntax

I'm using Python 2.7.11+ on linux mint.

```
print(Time,today.hour,':',today.minute,sep=''
```

And i am getting sytanx error at equally.I cant figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the `)` is missing at the end, but that is not the problem here:
What you are trying to do doesn't work in python 2.X, it's python3 syntax and it would have worked fine in python3.